# How to duplicate a Mongoid object - but also duplicate all the objects that it has relations to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have thses 2 `Mongoid` classes:

```
class LiveCustomer < Customer
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :mail_address, type: String
  has_many :live_emails, :inverse_of => :live_customer
end

class LiveEmail < Email
  include Mongoid::Document 

  field :mail_address, type: String
  belongs_to :live_customer, :inverse_of => :live_emails
end
```

And then I have the classes `SimCustomer` and `SimEmail` that looks exactly the same.

I now want to copy all objects of `LiveCustomer` to `SimCustomer`, and I want to copy all objects of `LiveEmail` to `SimEmail`. But how do I maintain the relations?

Because this implementation will only copy the objects, not the relations:

```
LiveEmail.all.each do |live_email|
  SimEmail.create(live_email.attributes)
end

LiveCustomer.all.each do |live_customer|
  SimCustomer.create(live_customer.attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wanna a full copy of the document to another collection, including ID and FKs, What I would do is get the raw document, and insert in the new collection using Moped(driver). Something like this:

```
LiveEmail.all.each do |live_email|
  SimEmail.collection.insert(live_email.as_document)
end
```

Comment: Hi Arthur. I am not sure that I am following. You would invoke this on the `Email` sub classes (that belongs to the `Customer` sub classes)? How would this copy over the `Customer` sub classes? Also, I tried to implement this, but nothin was copied over.